# How linearly increase and decrease height of Horizontal RecycleView in android

Tags: android

I have Horizontal cyclic ReacycleView. but I want in recycle view's middle item(ImageView) height be greater as compared to other side items.
[Recycle view items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTlq1.jpg)
 That means if any item in the center of RecycleView, it's height should be greater in RecycleView itself.

Comment: You have just one item? Is it a text view?

Comment: Post your adapter and layout xml that you showing using recycler view

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Add more details and the code you have till now

Comment: seems like carousel behavior you need?

Comment: yes ..I have only one item.. that is image view

Answer (score 0):

You can use a different layout for your middle item by implementing `getItemViewtype()` in your adapter. Similar question and answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245139/how-to-create-recyclerview-with-multiple-view-type) should point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks Ivan ...But i've only one item in recycle view. Please find the updated question and recycle view image

Comment: Can anyone help... It's urgent

Answer (score 0):

I created a sample app with this functionality and here is code.
Let me know if you need some explanation.

[image: Screenshot]

You need to create A custom layout manager and Item Transformer

[CenterLayoutManager](https://github.com/AadityaDev/CenteredLayoutManager/blob/master/feature/src/main/java/com/aditya/recyclerviewcentered/feature/view/CenterLayoutManager.java)

[Repository](https://github.com/AadityaDev/CenteredLayoutManager)

[ScaleTransformer](https://github.com/AadityaDev/CenteredLayoutManager/blob/master/feature/src/main/java/com/aditya/recyclerviewcentered/feature/impl/ScaleTransformer.java)

Comment: How can we make it cyclcic? means clockwise and anticlockwise it should have to scroll.

Comment: it can be scrolled in both directions, can you explain in more detail.

Comment: yeh...It is scrolling in both direction but it should be circular.

Comment: means if i scroll 1st time left. last item of list should have to display

Comment: finally, I found the solution. need to add  layoutManager.attach(recyclerView, Integer.MAX_VALUE/2);